# codeigniter-set selected value from dynamic dropdown

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, html-select

i want to create edit form in my page by using dynamic dropdown but i got problem with how to set selected value to the dynamic dropdown.
is there any way to set value without using onchange on javascript?, so when the first dropdown get selected value,the second dropdown will get dropdown content automatically.

my controller which to get the 'city' by 'province':

```
public function getCity($id){
    $tmp    = '';
    $data   = $this->query->getcity($id);
    if(!empty($data)){
        $tmp .= "<option value=''>-choose city-</option>"; 
        foreach($data as $row) {    
            $tmp .= "<option value='".$row->id_city."'>".$row->city."</option>";
        }
    } else {
        $tmp .= "<option value=''>-choose city-</option>"; 
    }
    die($tmp);
```

}

my javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#prov').change(function(){
           $.post("<?php echo base_url();>index.php/employer/ambilkota/"+$('#prov').val(),{},function(obj){
        $('#city').html(obj);
        });
        });



 });
```

Comment: The idea is adding the defaults through your controller, so when first opening the edit page, You'll load the cities list & have the current city selected (separate logic -- use the javascript only when changing not for loading deafults).

Comment: then how to have the current city selected?can you give me an example?

Comment: You can use a helper function to generate dynamic dropdown control initially with default value. Then load with first dropdown onchange. I am doing the same.